# Phase plot of a system of differential equations using Matlab

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions, matlab

Assume the system:
 \begin{align}
  \begin{pmatrix} 
           x \\
           y \\
         \end{pmatrix}'   &= \begin{pmatrix} 
           7x+10y+3 \\
           -5x-7y+1 \\
         \end{pmatrix}
  \end{align}

By changing the variables so that $(0,0)$ is the equilibrium point, the system transforms to:
\begin{align}
  \begin{pmatrix} 
           x_1 \\
           x_2 \\
         \end{pmatrix}'   &= \begin{pmatrix} 
            7x_1+10x_2\\
           -5x_1-7x_2 \\
         \end{pmatrix} = A \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
\end{pmatrix}
  \end{align}
After that, all we have to do in order to determine the equilibrium point's type and stability is to examine $A$'s eigenvalues.

Now, I would like to plot this system's solutions and its behavior near the equilibrium point using **Matlab**. Do I have to use the **ode45** command to solve the system and then graph its solutions or is there a quicker way to obtain the phase plot?

Could someone provide me with the code which does that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [quiver](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html) for this

```
[x1, x2] = meshgrid(-1.0 : 0.2 : 1.0, -1.5 : 0.2 : 1.5);
u = 7 * x1 + 10 * x2;
v = -5 * x1 - 7 * x2;

figure
quiver(x1, y1, u, v)
```

From this representation you can see that solution will circle around $(x_1, x_2) = (0, 0)$, clockwise

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One option is John Polking's [pplane](https://math.rice.edu/~dfield/).